# Java validation annotation @Pattern with regexp of \\\\ doesn't work properly

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need to do a validation for one of the request fields. I use annotation @Pattern for this.

```java
@Size(min = 3, max = 1000)
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9A-Za-z\\\\/]+")
private String name;
```

That is, I must be able to enter the latin letters, numbers, slash and backslash. With this pattern, when I trying to write something like `name/\` (looks like "`name/\\`" in Postman) I get an error

```
Unexpected internal error near index 6\r\nname/\\
```

**UPDATE:**

I did pattern `[////]+` and it works! But when I added the alphabet again, the problem came back. I noticed that the stack trace looks different than it does for validation. The error occurs on the following line:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(name, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I use this to check if the same name exists in the *MongoDB*.

Comment: Did you try `@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9A-Za-z\\/]+")`?

Comment: @g00se, yes, IntelliJ says `Redundant character escape '\\/' in RegExp` and remove ```\\```

Comment: @g00se 4 backslashes are actually correct: The Java String `"[\\\\]"` results in the regex `[\\]` and that is the escaping for the `\ ` literal to add to the character class.

Comment: @g00se, yes, I tried to use \\/ but it returned status 400 and MethodArgumentNotValidException.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with validation and not postman or your web framework itself, i.e. could it be that the error occurs even before validation? Please post the stacktrace for that error (it being an unexpected error should mean there is a stacktrace).

Comment: @Thomas, You seem to be right. This error occurs elsewhere. I will update the question.